# Custom model binder for model inner property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My model is like this

```
public class MyModel
{
   string ID {get;set;}
   string Title {get;set;}
   MyOtherModel Meta {get;set;}
}
```

How to define custom model binder for type (MyOtherModel) so when default binder binds MyModel it calls custom model binder for 'Meta' property.
I registered it in App start like:

```
 ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(MyOtherModel)] = new MyCustomBinder();
```

but this doesn't work. Any idea or any good article with more infor regarding to model binders?

Comment: What is not working? Have you tried putting a breakpoint into your custom binder to see if the binder has been associated correctly?

I usually use the syntax ModelBinders.Bonders.Add(typeof(MyOtherModel), new MyCustomBinder())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article about collections that touches a bit the complex type mapping stuff:

[Collections and a bit about complex types](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

In the other hand this article could give you some useful tips:

http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

I suggest you as a **workaround** to use a model binder for MyModel class, it's not a perfect solution but you can **refactor** it easily once you discover a better solution. : )

Answer (score 0):

Actually, If you will put in some Edit/Create View with Model of your MyModel class something like this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Meta.Prop1") %>
```

where Prop1 is property of your MyOtherModel class,
then

```
UpdateModel(model);
```

will populate textbox value to your custom submodel property. And back, textbox value would be populated with that submodel value as well.

So, once you update your current model, you are updating submodels too.

Comment: I mean the Prop1 is null no matter what

Comment: I have Ad class and Map class. Map is a property of Ad (Linq to SQL).
<%= Html.TextBox("Map.Zoom", Model.Map.Zoom)%> is working well and updating Map model Zoom property.
Please add FormCollection as parameter to your action:

public ActionResult Create(FormCollection forms)

and see which fields are coming to your action. Then we can check what's going wrong.

P.S. you should call UpdateModel for your primary model. Are you?